# Failed to create symbolic link

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, symlink, capifony

I'm trying to deploy my "develop" branch to my development server but when I run `cap development deploy`, I get the following error:

```
executing "ln -nfs /var/www/xyz.co.uk/shared/web/media /var/www/xyz.co.uk/releases/20130311143220/web/media"
    servers: ["x.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [x.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] ln:
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] failed to create symbolic link `/var/www/xyz.co.uk/releases/20130311143220/web/media'
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: x.xx.xx.xxx] 
    command finished in 44ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

When I look on the server `/var/www/xyz.co.uk/shared/web/media` has been created and `/var/www/xyz.co.uk/releases/20130311143220` is created but then once the symlink fails then `20130311143220` is deleted as its rolled back. Any ideas? Im ssh'ing as root.

**Capifony Configuration**

deploy.rb

```
set :stage_dir, 'app/config/deploy' # needed for Symfony2 only
set :stages, %w(production staging development)

set :application, "xyz.co.uk"

set :user, "root"  # The server's user for deploys
set :repository, "git@github.com:xyz/#{application}.git"
set :scm,         :git

set :keep_releases,  3
set :use_sudo,       false
set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,   [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/media", "vendor"]
set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, true
set :dump_assetic_assets, true

require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

development.rb

```
server 'x.xx.xx.xxx', :app, :web, :primary => true
ssh_options[:port] = xxxx
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/xyz.co.uk/"
set :symfony_env_prod, "test"
```

**UPDATE**

The actual error message is:

```
failed: "sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/xyz.co.uk/shared/web/media /var/www/xz.co.uk/releases/20130312135615/web/media'" on x.xx.xx.xxx
```

Also, here is my .gitignore file:

```
/web/bundles/
/app/bootstrap*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/vendor/
/app/config/parameters.yml
composer.phar
/.idea/
/web/media/*
```

Does it make a difference that my username and password to pull from my git repository is different on my Development server than on my local machine where I am deploying from?

Comment: We might need your Capifony configuration.

Comment: Ok give me 2 mins and I'll update my question.

Comment: Question updated with Capifony configuration.

Comment: Any idea @ElnurAbdurrakhimov ?

Comment: Anyone have any idea??

Comment: Updated initial question with gitignore file. Also, my git username and password on my development server is different to my local machine. Do these have to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because I hadn't set `set_branch` to develop so it was using master which was empty!

Comment: 3 years, but you never gave up! I love the spirit.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository server (bitbucked, github), the media folder has been pushed? It seems capifony tries to set as shared a folder that doesn't exist.

Comment: No, there is no media folder in my GIT repository because I've ignored it within .gitignore.